# run a php script in aws EC2 server using lambda

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup EC2 and RDS on it for an app, now I want to call a script present on the EC2 server (ubuntu, Apache running) every day (which is a sort of trigger for another service) to run within EC2, or a way to run that PHP script on Lambda itself removing EC2 from it.

What I did find was about python script and this: [Serverless PHP on AWS Lambda – Rob Allen's DevNotes](https://akrabat.com/serverless-php-on-aws-lamda/)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: PHP on AWS Lambda**

If you can get PHP working on Lambda, then that solves half your question. You can then schedule it using Amazon CloudWatch Events. Simple create a rule with a schedule to trigger the Lambda function.

**Option 2: Triggering script on Amazon EC2 instance**

If you just want to trigger a script on an Amazon EC2 instance, you can use a local `cron` definition.

If your intention was to only run the EC2 instance for the script and then turn off, then:

- Configure the **script** to run when the instance starts up (configure the operating system to run the script)
- Configure an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to run an AWS Lambda function once per day
- The **Lambda function** should start the instance
- When the script on the instance has completed its work, it should call the operating system to **shutdown** the instance. This will cause EC2 to stop it.

Instead of starting and stopping an instance, you could instead **Launch and Terminate an instance**. In this case, supply the script as User Data and it will automatically run after launch. Configure the instance Shutdown Behavior as *Terminate*.

Comment: i don't want to stop EC2 instance, the EC2 is my main server running apache on which other scripts are also present, i just want to run a specific script which is a sort of 'trigger', in my case that script is in php. Also the referred link isn't a solution, but seemed like one, it's too intricate for me to understand.

Comment: Also point out if it's the incorrect direction of handling it in such way or add that simply it isn't possible to achieve, i'm working my way up by learning & understanding how something works & what's possible.

Comment: If you have an existing EC2 instance and you want to run a script on that instance on a schedule, then you can use [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux).

Comment: Cron is the best way to do the scheduling (without knowing more context about your application)

Comment: For posterity: PHP can run in lambda with little effort if you implement the https://bref.sh/

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, your second answer is the one i needed, now all i need to see is how to upvote/accept your second answer as the one that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm currently doing this is by calling the script through HTTP using Node.

First, I have set up an AWS Lambda function like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const https = require('https');

    https.get('https://www.example.com/myscript?secret-token', (resp) => {});
};
```

The secret token is just so that I'm the only one who can execute this script by going to that URL.

Next, I schedule it to run on an EventBridge trigger, with a schedule expression similar to the following:

```
cron(0 8 * * ? *)
```

Which makes AWS Lambda call that URL every day 5am local time for me, 8am UTC.